# Rx.js concurrency with promises

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, rxjs

I want to process an array of objects by moving them through a series of async/network operations (remote HTTP requests).

In some of these operations I would like to ensure no more than X items are being processed at the same time.

How can I achieve that?

Example code:

```
function someAsyncOp(item) {...} // returns a promise

var source = Rx.Observable.from([{item1},{item2},...])
source
  .flatMap((item) => {

    // I WANT THE FOLLOWING OPERATION TO BE EXECUTING  
    // ON AT MAX 10 ITEMS AT A TIME, NEXT ITEM SHOULD
    // BE SUBMITTED ONLY WHEN A SLOT GETS FREED AS A 
    // RESULT OF THE PROMISE SUCCEEDING OR FAILING

    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(someAsyncOp(item))

  })
  .subscribe(
    console.log, 
    console.error, 
    () => console.log('completed')
  )
```

Comment: put take(X) before .flatMap [see interactive diagramm](http://rxmarbles.com/#take)

Comment: @valery.sntx this is gonna stop my source stream after the first X which means all subsequent items will never be processed.. I guess. I want all items to be processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an sibling of `flatMap` called `flatMapWithMaxConcurrent` which takes a concurrency argument. It is functionally similar to `map(fn).merge(n)` which was suggested by Benjamin's answer.

```
function someAsyncOp(item) {...} // returns a promise

var source = Rx.Observable.from([{item1},{item2},...])
source
   //Only allow a max of 10 items to be subscribed to at once
  .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(10, (item) => {

    //Since a promise is eager you need to defer execution of the function
    //that produces it until subscription. Defer will implicitly accept a promise
    return Rx.Observable.defer(() => someAsyncOp(item))

    //If you want the whole thing to continue regardless of exceptions you should also
    //catch errors from the individual processes
                        .catch(Rx.Observable.empty())
  })
  .subscribe(
    console.log, 
    console.error, 
    () => console.log('completed')
  )
```

Comment: i think the `.defer(...` part is what i was looking for. also the error handling part will be useful

Comment: any idea on how to manage concurrency in case of `withLatestFrom` in place of `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` with `map` instead of `flatMap`:

```
var concurrency = 10;
source.map(someAsyncOp).merge(concurrency).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Note that since promises are eager and observables are lazy fromPromise wouldn't cut it (and Rx can assimilate promises without it anyway). I recommend wrapping it in a `create`.

```js
var delay = function(ms){ return new Promise(function(r){ setTimeout(r, 2000, ms) }); }

var log = function(msg){ document.body.innerHTML += msg + "<br />"; }

Rx.Observable.range(1000, 10).map(delay).merge(2).subscribe(log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js"></script>
```